# Layout as a handle of SlidingDrawer on Android

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I have a typical SlidingDrawer in my app, but i don't know how to make a Layout(Relative or Linear) as a handle of my Slidingdrawer! ImageViews and Buttons work fine, but not a Layout!! Can you help me?

Comment: Post your code so that reply would be much faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sliding drawer xml you just set the handle id as the id of the new RelativeLayout/LinearLayout you want.  Just like you would a ImageView/Button etc.

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
    android:handle="@+id/drawerHandle"
    android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerHandle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but can i place two or more views in this layout? If yes, how can i pose these views? (android:gravity="left" doesn't work)

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand.  The handle would be written just like any other view, from my usage.  Can you be a bit more specific on what you want to put in the handle, etc?

Comment: well, i understood all except one thing. I have a layout in the handle. Can i bring the layout to the left or to the right? Something like defining android:gravity="left" in the SlidingDrawer?

Comment: Do you mean you want the SlidingDrawer to be horizontal and not vertical?  That would be setting the orientation property of the SlidingDrawer.

Comment: Or you could use the `alignParentLeft="true"`, if that is closer to what you meant by the gravity.

Comment: no, i want to bring LAYOUT to the left, not SlidingDrawer. But LAYOUT always stays in the center